# On drug-like criteria and QM9 dataset

Tags: cheminformatics, medicinal-chemistry

According to the book [Machine Learning Meets Quantum Physics](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-030-40245-7.pdf)

> QM9 is built up from $\sim 134 \mathrm{k}$ drug-like molecules with up
> to nine heavy atoms (C, N, O, or F).

I'm assuming that *drug-like molecule* is referring to [Lipinski's rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipinski%27s_rule_of_five). I used RDKit to plot 2D histogram of octanol-water partition coefficients (LogP) based on molecular weight (MolWt) and Polar Surface Area (PSA) based on molecular weight (MolWt)

[image]
[image]

These plots show that all molecules in the QM9 are below the suggested molecular weight interval of 180 to 480 and half the molecules have LogP below the -0.4 to 5.1 interval suggested by Ro5. I was wondering why they are called drug-like molecules? I'm using the following code to compute the properties:

```
from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors, Crippen

Descriptors.TPSA(mol)
Descriptors.MolWt(mol)
Crippen.MolLogP(mol)
```

Comment: Both the criteria you listed seem to under the variants of rule. The initial rules just say below 500 dalton and below 5 partition coefficient.

Comment: You are right. Seems my mind was biased by the numerous references that gave a lower bound of 200 for MW and looked over the earlier section. Now it makes sense why every paper that I read gave a slightly different definition.